# How to keep type information when destructuring an array of two types in typescript?

Tags: typescript

How can I concatenate two arrays of different type `A` and `B` and keep it with separate typings as a result and not just

```
Array<A | B>
```

and destructuring array back I want to keep types

```
const [a1, a2] = concatenated;
const [,, b1, b2] = concatenated;
```

Comment: Could you write the contents of concatenated?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with arbitrary length arrays. If they have fixed lengths, then you can handle it:

```
const a = [1,2] as [number, number];
const b = ['hello', 'bye'] as [string, string];

const c = [...a, ...b] as [number, number, string, string];
const [w, x, y, z] = c; // w and x are numbers, y and z are strings.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use extra function for this purpose:

```js
type Value = string | number

const concat = <
    A extends Value,
    ATuple extends A[],
    B extends Value,
    BTuple extends B[]
>(a: [...ATuple], b: [...BTuple]): [...ATuple, ...BTuple] => [...a, ...b]


// [1, 2, "hello", "bye"]
const result = concat([1, 2], ['hello', 'bye'])

const [a /** 1 */, b, c /** "hello" */, d] = result
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK7QLxQM7AE4EsB2A5lAD5T5IC2ARhNgLABQTAxgPb5ZTv4tzBR0AHiZQxUAIJQIAD2AR8AEwyxEKADSjxEgCpIwCaLPlKVEgNoBdTY3FQAQtLkLlq5BBt37eg0eemHKyYAPgAKOAAuKHMAOjjdfUNrKGoo2LjvRIhLAEo0uJiE33UoAszfS0Fg6IK4EoLqSyZmxgB6VuiARhKAJhKAIgALCAQENn6B6hAIfqbGHi5sCAwkBAF0Hj5gUPNuqB7k8wByYdG2I5KjqYgj3JaFgXM6lJKWEsVK9CWVtaA)

Thanks to function argument inference, every element of the tuple is properly infered

More information avout inference on function arguments you can find in my [blog](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)